# Why Punjabi (Indian Language) appears as boxes on some smart devices?

Tags: android, html, xcode, fonts

I have released an app called `Gurbani Ujagar`. It appears to work fine on some smartphones like the `Samsung Galaxy S3`, but other phones such as the `Galaxy Nexus`, `Galaxy S`, and on some tablets, the words/characters appear to be as boxes or random punctuation. I have over 1000 HTML files which are being viewed using `WebView`.

I am not sure how I can fix this problem so the text appears exactly the same on all the phones. I have checked some other `Punjabi` apps on `Galaxy Nexus` and the `Galaxy S`, namely `Dhur Ki Bani` (which appears fine), but the `Gurbani Ujagar` app appears as boxes. I am not sure why that is. I tried editing the font in a HTML file.

Text does appear on the phones that didn't show up before I started editing, but some text still renders incorrectly.

Editing more than 1000 pages manually would be a lot of work. The HTML (not source code) files are in my assets folder. Is it possible to edit all the HTML files using `Typeface`? It seems like I can edit all of them at once in `Xcode` but I am not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is an example of my code:

You can also [view the HTML file here](https://sites.google.com/site/gurbaniujagar/page1).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.html");        
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you list what's in your `3.html` file?

Comment: Yes, please see above.

Comment: I see that your text is encoded using UTF-8 and one of your characters decoded as GURMUKHI LETTER DA or U-0A26.  My guess is that font being used on the devices that do not display characters do not have glyphs for the Gurmukhi alphabet. I'm trying to search to see if there's a way that you can embed a web font in your pages.

Comment: Thank you so much, I searched a lot of forums, stackoverflow questions but found no luck. I hope either you or someone can find a solution to fix this.

Comment: if u want to show this then you need to use punjabi font in ur app , then ur app will run on any phone boxes will not shown

Comment: as like my app , in this i have place hindi font and it will shows as like this 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rimpv.jokes

Comment: In that case, I tried editing my HTML file with SamsungPunjabi.ttf. That did show the text but still many texts were misplaced. Whereas on some phones it shows up perfectly okay.

Comment: Where is your font hosted? As in can you tell us/link us the location of the font (be it local or provided by someone else)?

Answer (score 3):

Characters appear as boxes if the font you are using does not have glyphs for those characters (the font doesn't have those letters).

Some phones provide more fonts than others, and some phones may have more complete and newer versions of a font than others, meaning that some phones will have the font you selected and that font will have the characters you are using, while other versions of the same font on different phones or Android versions may not be as complete, and won't have the characters you use, so they will be displayed as boxes on those phones.

If you want to guarantee that your app will work and display all text on all phones, find a free font on [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) or [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) with a license that allows embedding in an app, and then ship that custom font with your app and use it in your HTML with CSS `@font-face`.

Comment: How do we solve this problem on websites? Punjabi chars display as boxes in browsers.

Comment: @jaspreet21anand read my answer. ***"find a free font on Google Webfonts or Font Squirrel"*** that has the characters that you need, and use it on your website.